# Chai POST request test does not send email

Tags: node.js, api, unit-testing, testing, chai

New to unit testing an API.

Using Chai, I am trying to test a POST request to an API.
Basically, the POST request should add the details into the database and send a confirmation email to the entered email address.

My tests checks for the data been added to the database. But whenever the test is run, it does not sends the confirmation email from the POST request.

Answer (score 3):

It is best not to send emails or talk to database for unit testing. One easy way to test is to create a spy using something like sinon. Read here about sinonjs - http://sinonjs.org/. Create a spy for the database call and check if the spy was called with the correct data. You can also create another spy for the email sending call and test if it was called with the correct email address.

Comment: I agree. One should not access other services or modules while unit testing. Mocking services is way better. (Integration testing is something else, though)